# How to avoid calling cometd serversession listener while reloading the page in browser instead of closing the window?

Tags: java, jquery, comet, cometd

I am working with cometd library for pushing notifications to web page here I am facing one problem i.e., whenever I am reloading (refreshing) the browser page

```
 ServerSession.addListener(new ServerSession.RemoveListener() {.......}
```

this method is calling unfortunately in some browsers how to avoid calling this listener,actually this listener should call whenever window closes or any click event occurs on link,So please help me to achieve this.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the calling `ServerSession.addListener(new ServerSession.RemoveListener() {.......}` while reloading the page in mozilla firefix and opera browsers just comment the `$.cometd.disconnect();` and use `window.onpagehide` instead of `window.unload` because `window.unload` will call while refreshing the page in mozilla and opera browsers.It fit for me perfectly.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [reload extension](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_extensions_reload) does what you need.

With the reload extension, refreshes of the same page or click on links that move to other pages of the same CometD application will avoid that the client re-handshakes with the server, therefore keeping the original session across reloads or links.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion sbordet and one more thing i would like to know where exactly the client is getting removed from the session i would like to know the exact function in jquery while reloading the page and the session is maintaining fine in google chrome but this reloading problem is coming in firefox and opera browsers.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. The session is removed by the server when it times out after `maxInterval`. As far as I know, the mechanism works in the same way in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks @sbordet i found the solution by your reference i was used window.onpagehide for avoiding the page refreshing problem and i commented `$.cometd.disconnect();` method for for avoiding the calling of listener `ServerSession.addListener(new ServerSession.RemoveListener() {.......}` while reloading the page in mozilla and opera browsers thank you very much